# Uploading multiple file with json data in same request to spring restful api

Tags: angularjs, label

I want to send json data with some file attachments to the spring restful api using angularjs. 
Now my problem is that, I have been able to send json data with a single file, but unable to do the same with more that one file(attachments). When I try uploading more than one file, the get an empty list in my restful controller method.

```
<form /> 
   <input type="text" -ng-model="ctrl.propertyForRent.caption" name="caption" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter the caption" required /> 
   <input type="file" file-model="photos" name="photo" accept="image/*" multiple /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide some source code please?

Comment: Please update your question

Comment: <form />

<input type="text" -ng-model="ctrl.propertyForRent.caption" name="caption" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Enter the caption" required />
<input type="file" file-model="photos" name="photo" accept="image/*" multiple />

</form>

Comment: My Directive is here

Comment: 'use strict';

UnmasmsApp.directive('fileModel', [ '$parse', function($parse) {
 // FileList

 return {
  restrict : 'A',
  link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
   element.bind('change', function() {
    $parse(attrs.fileModel).assign(scope, element[0].files)
    scope.$apply();
   });
  }
 };

} ]);

Comment: The opening form tag should not contain backslash (closing it). Also there should not be - before ng-model.

Comment: The controller is here below

Comment: UnmasmsApp .controller( 'PropertyForRentController', [ '$scope', 'PropertyForRentService', 'fileUpload', function($scope, PropertyForRentService, fileUpload) {
var self = this;
self.propertyForRent = {id : null, description : '', caption : '' };
 
 self.createPropertyForRent = function(propertyForRent) {
 var files = $scope.photos;
 console.log('file is ');
 console.dir(files);
 PropertyForRentService .createPropertyForRent(propertyForRent, files).then(
  self.fetchAllPropertyForRents, function(errResponse) {
   console .error('Error while creating PropertyForRent.'); });
 };
} ]);

Comment: The Service is here

Comment: UnmasmsApp.factory('PropertyForRentService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

   return {
    createPropertyForRent: function(propertyForRent, files){
    var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("propertyForRent", angular.toJson(propertyForRent));
                formData.append("file", files); 
                console.log(formData)
                console.log(files.length);
     angular.forEach(files, function(
      file, i) {
     formData.append("file", file); 
     console.log(file)
    })

Comment: Continuation //formData.append("arrayKey", "");
     $http.post('http://localhost:8181/estates/propertyForRent/savePropertyForRent/',
     formData, {
     transformRequest: angular.identity,
     headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
     })
          .success(function (callback) {
                   // recieve image name to use in a ng-src
                    console.log(callback);
                })
          .error(function(){
          });
          }

Comment: You can actually edit your question to include this code, you don't have to post it in comments.

Comment: Spring restful api

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/savePropertyForRent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<Void> createPropertyForRent(String propertyForRent,
   @RequestParam("file") ArrayList<MultipartFile> files) throws ValidationFailedException,
   IOException, JSONException {
  PropertyForRent property = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
    propertyForRent, PropertyForRent.class);
  System.out.println(property.getDescription());
   if (!files.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("========= Check it ===========");
        }
  return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}